# Run Prolog queries within prolog file and store the result in a txt file

Tags: prolog

I have a prolog file `test1.P`mention below, I want to test multiple queries on this file, for this reason i have added 3-loops (query1,query2,quer3): I want to store the result of the query and time that query has took for evaluation to text file "result.txt". the problem is this code works fine but it only store the result of the last query in the file and does not store the time along side with query.

```
sol(Goal, Pair) :-
   term_variables(Goal, Vars),
   findall(Vars, Goal, Substs),
   write_list_to_file('result.txt',Substs),
   Pair = Vars-Substs.
   
ans(Goal, Pair):- statistics(runtime,[Start|_]),
sol(Goal, Pair),
statistics(runtime,[Stop|_]),
Runtime is Stop - Start,
write(Runtime).

loop_through_list(File, List) :-
    member(Element, List),
    write(File, Element),
    write(File, ' '),
    fail.

write_list_to_file(Filename,List) :-
    open(Filename, write, File),
    \+ loop_through_list(File, List),
    close(File).
    
:- forall(ans((pred1(X,Y),pred2(X,'BaldEagle')),L), writeln(L)). //query1
:- forall(ans((pred1(X,Y), pred3(X,'Eagle')),L), writeln(L1)). //quer2
:- forall(ans((pred1(X,Y), pred4(Y,Z)),L), writeln(L2)). //query3
```

So instead of using 3 queries in **test1.P** I have created another file named as **testQueries.P** and write my queries like this:

```
query(ans((pred1(X,Y),pred2(X,'BaldEagle')),L), writeln(L)).
query(ans((pred1(X,Y), pred3(X,'Eagle')),L), writeln(L1)).
query(ans((pred1(X,Y), pred4(Y,Z)),L), writeln(L2)).

myforall(X,Y) :- \+ (X, \+ Y).
mywrite(T) :- write(T), nl.
mycount(Query, Count) :-
                setof(Query, Query, Set),
                length(Set, Count),
                Count = 0.
test :-
    mycount(query(Q), Count).    
    myforall(query(Q), (Q -> mywrite(yes:Q); mywrite(no:Q))),
    halt.


:- initialization(['test1.P']).
:- initialization(test).
```

But still I am unable to store the results of all the queries and time in the text file. Also how can i get the number of results generated against query?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is twofold:

- You perform `write(Runtime)` of the "runtime in milliseconds" without the `File` as argument. Consequently, the output goes to "standard output" (or maybe "current output"), i.e. the terminal, not the file.
- For each query, you open the file as `open(Filename, write, File)`,  write whatever you want to write, then close the file. The file is opened in `write` mode, which is really `truncation` mode: The file emptied, and writing begins anew at file position 0. This explains why only the information regarding the last query is seen. You have to either open the file in `append` mode: `open(Filename, append, File)` or write all that you want to write before closing the file.

An improved `write_list_to_file/3`, where we use `forall/2` instead of a "failure-driven loop":

```
write_list_to_file(Filename,List,Mode) :-
    must_be(oneof([write,append]),Mode),
    setup_call_cleanup(    
       open(Filename, Mode, File),  % but what's the encoding? It depends!
       forall(
          member(Element,List),
          (
             write(File,Element),
             write(File,' ')
          )
       ),
       close(File)).
```

So, one has to call it once with `Mode = write` and twice with `Mode = append`. But this still doesn't help with getting the runtime milliseconds into the file.

The code is quite convoluted. Maybe it can be greatly simplified.

For example, this is still not ideal (in particular because it repeatedly opens and closes the file), but using the above `write_list_to_file/3`:

```
question1(X,Y) :-
   pred1(X,Y),
   pred2(X,'BaldEagle')).
   
question2(X,Y) :-
   pred1(X,Y), 
   pred3(X,'Eagle')),

question3(X,Y,Z) :-
   pred1(X,Y),
   pred4(Y,Z).
   
time_goal(Goal,VarsBindings,Delta_ms) :-
   statistics(runtime,[Start|_]),
   term_variables(Goal, Vars),
   findall(Vars,Goal,VarsBindings),
   statistics(runtime,[Stop|_]),  
   Delta_ms is Stop - Start.
   
time_goal(Goal,Filename,Mode) :-
   time_goal(Goal,VarsBindings,Delta_ms),
   write_list_to_file(Filename,[Goal,Delta_ms],Mode),
   write_list_to_file(Filename,VarsBindings,append).

time_all(Filename) :-
   time_goal(question1(X,Y),Filename,write),
   time_goal(question2(X,Y),Filename,append),
   time_goal(question3(X,Y,Z),Filename,append).
```

Comment: if i define "write_list_to_file/3" like this `write_list_to_file(Filename,List,Mode) :-
       open(Filename, Mode, File),  
       forall(member(Element,List),(write(File,Element),write(File,' '))),
    close(File).` then I get all the answers of 3 queries in the same file but the time is 0.